# Can't override background color with "none", only with "inherit"

Tags: css, windows-8

I was trying to remove the white background from the .win-container elements (the tiles) in a Windows 8 ListView control to let the background show through. When I traced the styles, I could see that the white background was getting applied with the following rule...

```
.win-listview :not(.win-footprint).win-container
```

So I wrote my own rule for that like this...

```
.win-listview :not(.win-footprint).win-container {
    background-color: none;
}
```

But that didn't work.

A friend helped me figure out that I could use...

```
.win-listview :not(.win-footprint).win-container {
    background-color: inherit;
}
```

And that works great. Can anyone tell me why in the world this is so?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`none` is a value of the `background-image` property, not `background-color`. Since it's not a valid value of `background-color`, the declaration is ignored and the system will continue drawing your tiles with the default white background. If you want to give your tiles a transparent background, you need to use `background-color: transparent` instead:

```
.win-listview :not(.win-footprint).win-container {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

(You can also use `background: none`, but again `none` represents `background-image` with an implied `transparent` for `background-color`.)

`background-color: inherit` simply tells your tiles to take on (or [inherit](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#inheritance)) the same background color as the `ListView` containing them. This may or may not have an apparent effect of having no distinct background color. However it is not the same as having a transparent background (unless the `ListView` itself also has a transparent background, which in your case it probably doesn't).

Comment: Thanks a million. I didn't know about the 'transparent' color value.